# FQL gives empty data from stream table for multiple source_id, but works properly for the Graph Api Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have been trying to run some FQL query from an app I have set up. The FQL is supposed to get last few posts from a list of pages using "source_id IN ()" clause. It works from the Graph Api Explorer (gives an array of post data), but fails for my app (gives an empty array). I have got access_token with read_stream permission in both cases.

This happens only for multiple pages. If I give just one page using "source_id = " clause, I get list of posts in both cases. I don't want to use multiple queries each containing a single page id, as the page list would be long and I need only a few pages.

Here is the FQL I am using in both cases :

```
SELECT post_id, message, place, updated_time, actor_id, like_info.like_count, share_info.share_count, comment_info.comment_count FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (331288023558058,186202548075080) AND actor_id = source_id LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is there anything I need to do in order to make this query work for my app?

Comment: did you solve this problem? same happening here. One thing I tried is diving manage_pages permission.

Comment: Nope, I tried with all the permissions without any result. I gave up on querying for multiple pages, and used the "source_id = " clause instead to query for only a given page at a time.